# Reactive Kafka not printing messages

Tags: apache-kafka, reactive-programming, akka-stream

Im looking to understand why the following code will actually print a

```
val consumerProperties = ConsumerProperties(
  bootstrapServers = "localhost:9092",
  topic = "test",
  groupId = "group",
  valueDeserializer = new StringDeserializer
).commitInterval(1200 milliseconds)

consumerWithOffSetSink = kafka.consumeWithOffsetSink(consumerProperties)
Source.fromPublisher(consumerWithOffSetSink.publisher)
    .map{ msg =>
      println(msg.value())
      msg
    }
  .to(consumerWithOffSetSink.offsetCommitSink).run()
```

Yet, the following code below doesn't do what Im expecting it to do:

```
val consumerProperties = ConsumerProperties(
  bootstrapServers = "localhost:9092",
  topic = "test",
  groupId = "group",
  valueDeserializer = new StringDeserializer
).commitInterval(1200 milliseconds)

consumerWithOffSetSink = kafka.consumeWithOffsetSink(consumerProperties)
Source.fromPublisher(consumerWithOffSetSink.publisher)
  .runForeach(msg => println(msg.value()))
  .foreach(msg => println(msg))
```

What Im trying to understand is how to structure my app for streaming, Im still in the processes of understanding `Akka Streams` overall, and how they work internally.